# How do half-elves decide if they live a short life like humans or a long one like elves?

Tags: saihate-no-paladin

In season 2 episode 2 of Saihate no Paladin, Meneldor mentions half elves have to decide if they live a short life like humans or a long one like elves. How do they decide this?